# Altering border's corner radius on WPF Expander control?

Tags: wpf, expander, cornerradius

Very high up the visual tree in WPF's `Expander` control is a border element (see screenshot). By default this has a `CornerRadius` of `3`. Is it possible to modify this value?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can change the control template. Expander template is available in msdn in the following link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave marking as answer for now but I managed to implement the solution as follows:

Using [stylesnooper](http://blog.tomaskafka.com/book/export/html/112) I obtained the style / control template used for the 'standard' `Expander` control.

Then after discovering it didn't quite behave as expected, figured out that the line `<ToggleButton IsChecked="False" ...` is wrong and should actually be `<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"...`

Everything then worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I made a `behavior` which modifies the first found `border` in the `ControlTemplate`. You can easily extend the behavior with new properties where u want to modify

---

```
/// <summary>
/// modifies the first found <see cref="Border"/> in the <see cref="ControlTemplate"/> of the attached <see cref="Control"/>
/// </summary>
public class ModifyBorderBehavior : Behavior<Control>
{
    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Properties
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The new corner radius
    /// </summary>
    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="CornerRadius"/> DependencyProperty.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(ModifyBorderBehavior));

    #endregion

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Constructor
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region Constructor

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += _OnLoaded;
    }

    private void _OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var children = VisualTree.GetVisualChildCollection<Border>(sender);            
        if (sender is Control control)
        {
            Border border = VisualTree.GetVisualChild<Border>(control);
            if(ReadLocalValue(CornerRadiusProperty) != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                border.CornerRadius = CornerRadius;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

---

```
<Expander>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <zls:ModifyBorderBehavior CornerRadius="0"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Expander>
```